# Google Cloud Dataprep can't import a BigQuery view across projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am working with Google Cloud Dataprep and cannot import a dataset from a Big Query view.

The view lives in Project A (where the Dataprep was set up) and is a select across a set of wildcard tables which live in Project B. It fails with this error: Preview not available. Permission denied. Please verify access to the data.

As per the [cross-project documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/concepts/cross-bq-datasets) I shared the Project B dataset with the dataprep service accounts.

To test this, I can import tables from Project A and B so the permissions seem fine.

If I copy the view to Project B, Dataprep can then import it successfully.

The problem seems to be where my Project A view selects from Project B tables. Is this a known limitation that anyone knows about?

Best regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation is known by the Dataprep team and are looking to fix it. I opened an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/118535490) to follow the progress of the issue. You can click on the star at the top of the page to get updates.

For the time being, granting the two service accounts below the BigQuery user role on a project level rather than on a dataset level will solve the issue.

```
service-<project-number>@trifacta-gcloud-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```